# Python - Search for one word but two are similar so i get both

Tags: python

ím searching through a .log file for a keyword and in this document are strings of test that I want to sort later but my problem I that there are two different strings that has the keyword... My search keyword is "Tester" but another string has  "Sending Request: Tester" so I get both strings when I print my keyword... How can I exclude the string with "Sending Request: Tester" and only print the "Tester" string? I have tried `if not, or, and, not, and others` but can´t get what I want... help please, is there some type of exclude function?

EDIT

```
if 'Tester' in lines:
data.append(lines)
data.remove('Sending Request: Tester')
print(data) # wont work...

if 'Tester' == lines:
data.append(lines)
print(data) # wont work
```

This is how the file looks like, I want to extract the tester string only "Tester ->" with numbers not "Sending Request: Tester ->"
with number..

```
    Sending Request: Tester -> 12341244
    Tester ->12341244
    Sending Request: Tester ->234314
    Tester ->234314
    Sending Request: Tester ->12342314
    Tester ->12342314
```

Comment: equality operator ought to do it. `if line == "Tester":` will succeed if the line is "Tester" and fail if the line is "Sending Request: Tester". If you're thinking, "no, I tried that, but it didn't work" or "yes, but that approach is unsuitable given the larger context of my program", please share your program and document.

Comment: can you post a snippet of your code? It is hard to answer otherwise... But an equality operator such as `==` should do the trick.

Comment: @Kevin I tried == and this is the code I have problem with, look edit

Comment: @Rachel look edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the function startswith

```
if lines.startswith('Tester'):
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm